# ASP.NET C# How to Change Data in a GridView and Write to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, datatable

I have a GridView that is returning data in this format:

```
Member ID  | Yesterday Pounds | Yesterday Tons | Yesterday Dollars | Total Pounds | Total Tons | Total Dollars
000100-001 | 10,000.00        |  5.00          | $10,000.00        | 1,000,000.00 | 3,000.00   | $2,000,000.00
000100-002 | 40,000.00        | 20.00          | $10,500.00        | 4,000,000.00 | 22,000.00  | $1,000,000.00 
000102-001 | 80,000.00        | 40.00          | $20,000.00        | 2,000,000.00 | 9,000.00   | $4,000,000.00
000200-005 | 40,000.00        | 20.00          | $14,000.00        |  600,000.00  | 300.00     | $200,000.00
```

I'm querying our database and have to compile and send information to another company in an XML document.

This first thing that I'm doing is converting our company ID to theirs, I've written a class that will do this. For example Member IDs 000100-001, 000100-002, and 000102-001 are all converted to 1200 and Member ID 000200-005 is converted to 1201.

I also need to total all of the columns by company ID. So for Member IDs 000100-001, 000100-002, and 000102-001 I need to sum up Yesterday Pounds, Yesterday Tons, Yesterday Dollars, Total Pounds, Total Tons, and Total Dollars and send the result as one row with Member ID 1200.  Member ID 00200-005 needs no action it is stand alone in this scenario. The result would look like this:

```
Member ID  | Yesterday Pounds | Yesterday Tons | Yesterday Dollars | Total Pounds | Total Tons | Total Dollars
   1200    | 130,000.00       |    65.00       |     $40,000.00    | 7,000,000.00 | 34,000.00  | $7,000,000.00
   1201    | 40,000.00        |    20.00       |     $14,000.00    | 600,000.00   |  300.00    | $200,000.00
```

I do have classes that convert the member ids and calculate the totals.  The problem I'm running across is that when the data is written to the XML it is writing all records, so I get three entries for id 1200, not just the last one with the totals.

So I thought I would move the data into a DataTable, iterate through it doing my calculations and then recreate the DataTable with only the records I want, then move the DataTable to XML.  Syntactically I'm having trouble figuring this out.
If there is a better approach, I'm all ears.  I welcome all suggestions.

Here is my code:

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDailyShipments" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="Gray" OnRowDataBound="grdDailyShipments_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MEMBERID" HeaderText="MEMBER ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MEMBERID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="YESTERDAYPOUNDS" HeaderText="YESTERDAY POUNDS" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:N}" SortExpression="YESTERDAYPOUNDS" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="YESTERDAYTONS" HeaderText="YESTERDAY TONS" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:N}" SortExpression="YESTERDAYTONS" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="YESTERDAYDOLLARS" HeaderText="YESTERDAY DOLLARS" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:C}" SortExpression="YESTERDAYDOLLARS" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTALPOUNDS" HeaderText="TOTAL POUNDS" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:N}" SortExpression="TOTALPOUNDS" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTALTONS" HeaderText="TOTAL TONS" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:N}" SortExpression="TOTALTONS" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTALDOLLARS" HeaderText="TOTAL DOLLARS" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:C}" SortExpression="TOTALDOLLARS" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind on GridView:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DailyReportRecordId", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ProgramID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("MemberID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("YesterdayPounds", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("YesterdayTons", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("YesterdayDollars", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("TotalPounds", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("TotalTons", typeof(decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("TotalDollars", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < grdDailyShipments.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    recordId = (i + 1).ToString();
    memberId = grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
    memberId = MemberIdConversion.convertId(memberId);
    yesterdayPounds = grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    yesterdayTons = grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
    yesterdayDollars = grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.ToString();

    // Get the value returned to the Grid
    totalPounds = Convert.ToDecimal(grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text.ToString());
    // Call combine totals to total all the subsidiaries
    totalPounds = CombineTotalPounds.combineTotalPounds(memberId, totalPounds);

    // Get the value returned to the Grid
    totalTons = Convert.ToDecimal(grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text.ToString());
    // Call combine totals to total all the subsidiaries
    totalTons = CombineTotalTons.combineTotalTons(memberId, totalTons);

    // Get the value returned to the Grid
    totalDollarsStr = grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text.ToString();
    // Strip off the $, if you don't to this the Convert.ToDecimal WILL NOT
    // work due to formatting issues
    totalDollarsStr = totalDollarsStr.Substring(1);
    // Convert the string to a decimal and round it. 
    totalDollars = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(totalDollarsStr), 2);
    // Convert back to a string. 
    totalDollarsStr = totalDollars.ToString();
    // Format to Currency. 
    totalDollarsStr = String.Format("{0:C}", totalDollars);

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = recordId;
    dr[1] = invoiceDateStr;
    dr[2] = "1202";
    dr[3] = memberId;
    dr[4] = yesterdayPounds;
    dr[5] = yesterdayTons;
    dr[6] = yesterdayDollars;
    dr[7] = totalPounds;
    dr[8] = totalTons;
    dr[9] = totalDollarsStr;

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("DailyReportRecordId");
    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", recordId);

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Date");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(invoiceDateStr);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ProgramID");
    xmlWriter.WriteString("1202");
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("MemberID");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(memberId);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("YesterdayPounds");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(yesterdayPounds);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("YesterdayTons");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(yesterdayTons);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("YesterdayDollars");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(yesterdayDollars);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("TotalPounds");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(totalPounds.ToString("#,##0.00"));
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("TotalTons");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(totalTons.ToString("#,##0.00"));
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("TotalDollars");
    //xmlWriter.WriteString(totalDollarsStr.ToString());
    xmlWriter.WriteString(totalDollarsStr);
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // End of Daily Report Record Id
}
```

I understand that each record is being written to the XML in the for loop as it iterates through the grid.  The Member ID conversion works, and so do the Totals.  To reiterate, the problem is that ONLY the last record (if there are multiple) has the correct totals, the ones above it are cumulative as the code progresses.

So now with the data in the DataTable I want to do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i ++)
{
     if(dt(i).memberid = dt(i - 1).memberid)
     (
       set variable here to write to XML
     )
}
```

But this is pseudo code because I'm having trouble figuring this out.

Again, if my approach is not the best, I'm open for ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to approach this, but the easiest based on what you already have would be to loop through your GridView backwards since you said that the you want to get the last row per each member-id. I've modified your psuedocode to show what I mean:

```
string lastId = null;    
for(int i = (dt.Rows.Count-1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(lastId == null || lastId != dt(i).memberid) 
    {
        //write XML, as we're at the last for the given memberid, 
        //assuming the GridView is sorted by memberid.
    }
    lastId = dt(i).memberid;
}
```

If the the member id's are not grouped, I would still go through the DataGrid backwards, but add a Dictionary or a List variable to keep track of memberIds have already been added to the XML:

```
List<string> memberIdsAddedToXml = new List<string>();    
for(int i = (dt.Rows.Count-1); i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(!memberIdsAddedToXml.Contains(dt(i).memberid))
    {
        memberIdsAddedToXml.Add(dt(i).memberid);
        //write XML, as we're at the last row for the given memberid
    }
}
```

Better, I think, would be to create a class (`Foo`) that represents the data in your grid view. Then create a method that returns list of `Foo` objects by looping through the grid view rows copying the data into a list. Create another method that takes a list of `Foo` objects and writes them to the XML document. And finally, create a method that combines the two previous methods. An example:

```
void ExportTotalsAsXml(DataTable dt, string xmlPath) 
{
     List<Foo> list = ExtractDataFromData(dt);
     List<Foo> filteredList = new List<Foo>
     //loop through the list backwards to get the total row per memberid, storing it in filteredList
     WriteToXml(filteredList, xmlPath);
}
```

By separating it out this way, you'll be able to easier see what each part is doing, especially when coming back to later to make changes or bug fixes.

Comment: I'll try the second suggestion, it looks like it might work.

Comment: This is one of my problems, dt(i) will not work.  I get "method name expected".  I can't seem to figure out how to reference a specific row in the DataTable.

Comment: Try `grdDailyShipments.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text` instead to get the member id cell. dt(i) was just psuedocode to avoid typing it all out. By the way, I don't think you need to use ToString() on the `Text` fields.

Comment: You may also be able to call `dt.Rows[i]["MemberID"]` to get the member id directly from the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it another go on Monday, my weekend is getting ready to start :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you right, but maybe this will help you in some way. You can use LINQ to count totals and write result in new DataTable then write DataTable into xml using DataTable.WriteXml method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx

```
dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("MemberID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("YesterdayPounds", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("YesterdayTons", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("YesterdayDollars", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("TotalPounds", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("TotalTons", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("TotalDollars", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("1200", 10000.00, 500, 10000.00, 1000, 3000.00, 2000000.00);
        dt.Rows.Add("1200", 10000.00, 500, 10000.00, 1000, 3000.00, 2000000.00);
        dt.Rows.Add("1201", 10000.00, 500, 10000.00, 1000, 3000.00, 2000000.00);
        dt.Rows.Add("1202", 10000.00, 500, 10000.00, 1000, 3000.00, 2000000.00);

        var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
          .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("MemberID"))
          .Select(g =>
          {
              var row = dt.NewRow();

              row["MemberID"] = g.Key;
              row["YesterdayPounds"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("YesterdayPounds"));
              row["YesterdayTons"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("YesterdayTons"));
              row["YesterdayDollars"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("YesterdayDollars"));

              return row;
          }).CopyToDataTable();

        ds = new DataSet();

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(result);

        result.WriteXml(@"G:\MyDataset.xml");
```